# Should revoke refress token when get new access token?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have API get new access token from refresh token but i wonder that:
should revoke refresh token and generate new refresh token when getting new access.

Case 1:
api/refresh token =>
{new_access_token,new_refresh_token} (refresh_token revoked)

Case 2:
api/refresh token =>
{access_token} (refresh_token not revoke)

What is bestpractive, im using Nestjs

Answer (score 0):

If you will revoke refresh token each time, user refreshes the token, you technically would be same as just going with 1 access token.
Best way to approach this, would be case 2. Though you would add some expiration to refresh token and then user would have to relogin again and regenerate refresh token.
The idea of refresh token is to somehow have control over your access token without sacrificing UX(User Experience). If you revoke refresh token each time, user will have to relogin. If you keep refresh token though, user would only have to relogin on refresh token revocation. On refresh token layer you could add database checks to check if user is banned. This way you save extra external calls on access token layer.
Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thank Edward, but when user get new access token i return both new access token and new reftesh token so user dont need relogin.If not remove refresh token when get new access token, Is it less secure?

Comment: @cheng I would remove new refresh token there, just extra tokens you generate for no reason. Since now you will have extra refresh tokens valid for creating new tokens for same user